# What values/fields can I get from stormcrawler?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika, stormcrawler, elasticsearch-7

I am using Stormcrawler 1.15, ElasticSearch 7.5, and followed this tutorial to get SC up and running: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTerugU12TY

In my crawler-conf.yaml I have:

```
  # indexer.md.filter: "someKey=aValue"
  indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
  indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
  - domain=domain
```

This suggests that I already have description and keywords, but as of now, I get in the documents of the 'content' index the fields: url, content, domain, title. For instance:

```
{
  "_index": "content",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "c31104689b7ab4e8152f70b755049e7060da3457f06d64993667df28f7be6811",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "content": "Startseite Gesetze / Verordnungen Aktualitätendienst [...]",
    "url": "http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/markeng_8bek_00-03-27/index.html",
    "domain": "gesetze-im-internet.de",
    "title": "MarkenG§8Bek 00-03-27 - nichtamtliches Inhaltsverzeichnis"
  }
}
```

But I would like to get more, like keywords, description, creation-date, crawl-date, for example. Maybe even a summary.

How can I get these?

What other values/fields can I get with this crawler?

How can I get them in ES?

I have heard that there is a way to make SC work with tika to parse html and pdf better, and this way maybe I can get more data and metadata from my crawled pages. But I still don't know how to do it. A guide/tutorial for this would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parse filters are configured correctly as [here](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources/parsefilters.json). The crawler can be configured or extended to extract pretty much anything, see [WIKI](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/ParseFilters) for a list of existing parse filters.

The Tika module won't do a better job with HTML docs compared to the JSOUP one but will handle other mime-types. See README of that module to see how to use it.